# make didUpdateValueForCharacteristic asynchronous

Tags: ios, asynchronous, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

currently I am working on a project that is uploading a file through BLE (ios)

Currently I have a loop to send all the data in the file and I close the loop once my pointer in the file has reached the end.

So on the firmware side the characteristics I am writing to updates from 0 to 100 as the progress indication of how many bytes the firmware has received.

my `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` is only being called after my loop ends because I believe they are synchronous and both working on the main thread.

I am trying to make my loop asynchronous so I can still listen to the method `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` while I am sending

```
dispatch_async(_sendFileQueue, ^{
    while (_isFileSending) {
    // File is still sending
    // Upload file from offset
    [self uploadFile:_offset];
 }
});
```

so I tried this, but I still get the update at the end of the loop, but I don't know if it is because the connection interval that I don't get a response on the iOS end. I know for certain the firmware is update the UUID as I am sending the file.

**Source for uploadFile**

```
- (void)uploadFile:(int)from {
    // Look at file from index from
    [_filePath seekToFileOffset:from];
    NSData *soundData = [_filePath readDataOfLength:_packetSize];
    // data it should be greater than 0 bytes
    if (soundData.length > 0) {
    [self connectToPeripherals:soundData];
       // Find new pointer
       _offset += _packetSize;
    } 
}


- (void)connectToPeripherals:(NSData *)data {
    // Using NSNumber since I want to check if I get a nil returned
    NSNumber *writeWithResponse = nil;

    CBPeripheral *firstPeripheral = self.peripherals[0];
    CBCharacteristic *firstCharacteristics = self.characteristics[0];

    // Check if properties have a response, if so write with response
    if((self.characteristicManager.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite)
   == CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite) {
        DLog(@"Write with response");
        writeWithResponse = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    } else if ((self.characteristicManager.properties &
            CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse) ==
           CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse) {
        DLog(@"Write without response");
        writeWithResponse = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    }
    // There is no write property
    if (!writeWithResponse) {
        DLog(@"ERROR! Could not write to characteristics");
        return;
    }
    // Write to the first peripheral
    [firstPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:firstCharacteristics
                       type:[writeWithResponse boolValue] ?
    CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse :    CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
}
```

**tl;dr** make `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` called in everything

Comment: You can choose a different queue for your delegate methods when you set up the CBCentralManager. How is `sendFileQueue` created?

Comment: @Paulw11 This is how I set up sendFileQueue  `_sendFileQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.test", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);`

Comment: At the end of the loop do you receive all of the updates from your peripheral or only the final value?  Can you show the source for  `uploadFile`

Comment: @Paulw11 I receive all the updates from my peripheral. The source of is up above

Comment: Ok, so now we need to see `connectToPeripherals`... So once you have finished sending you get, say, 10 calls to `didUpdateValue` with the intermediate values.

Comment: @Paulw11 added `connectToPeriperals` not clear what you are saying

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I understand what you are saying yes we do have 10 calls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90082/discussion-between-paulw11-and-picturemeandyou).